# how to calculate the angular velocity of end effector of two link robot arm?

Tags: robotic-arm

I am trying to calculate the angular velocity of end effector of two-link robot arm. Can anyone help me to find it?

If $q_1$, $q_2$  are joint angular position and $\dot{q_1}$ and $\dot{q_2}$ are joint angular velocities, and $\omega$ is angular velocity of end effector, then I use $\omega=\dot{q_1}+\dot{q_2}$.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, angular velocities are additive if that is all you're looking for (*i.e.,* $\omega_2$ expressed in the base frame of $\omega_1$).  If you are trying to find the velocity of a point on link 2, then you need to add an $\omega $x$ r$ term.

Answer (score 2):

Jacobian would help you in this case. The joint velocities and the end effector velocities are related by the following equation,

$$ \dot{X} = J(q).\dot{q} $$

Answer (score 0):

angular velocity is wrt the center axis.  a simple way to account for that is to calculate absolute cartesian velocities, it's something like

v1 = cos(q1) I + sin(q1) J

v2_absolute = v1 + cos(q2) I + sin(q2) J

where I and J are the unit vectors in the x, and y direction